# Why does my computer freeze when I add a subsurf modifier?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I have an object with over a million vertices. When I select subdivision surface, my Mac starts the rainbow circle and sits still. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Hello :). First, enabling Subsurf creates 4 million verts from your 1 mil. Second - Blender 2.8+ has speed issues when adding subsurf modifier. It's currently a recognized bug.